# Unable to umount after pivot_root

Tags: mount, chroot

On a board, I would like to flash the (NAND) partition where my current rootfs is without restarting and being able to check if the flash succeeded.

To do so, I try to:

- kill every unnecessary processes
- mount a SD card containing another rootfs (a mount point to the current rootfs will be available on the SD card)
- run pivot_root between the rootfs of the SD card and the original one
- run chroot to use the SD card root.
- unmount the old root partition
- flash a new rootfs
- pivot_root back on the rootfs partition

Unfortunately, I cannot unmount the original root partition.

The beginning is basically the steps described in the pivot_root manual page:

```
mount /dev/hda1 /new-root
cd /new-root
pivot_root . old_root
exec chroot . sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1
umount /old-root # <== unable to unmount
```

---

```
Killing some processes:

ps
```

> ```
>   PID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
>         1 root      1524 S    init [3]
>         2 root         0 SW<  [kthreadd]
>         3 root         0 SW<  [ksoftirqd/0]
>         4 root         0 SW<  [watchdog/0]
>         5 root         0 SW<  [events/0]
>         6 root         0 SW<  [khelper]
>       126 root         0 SW<  [kblockd/0]
>       132 root         0 SW<  [kseriod]
>       136 root         0 SW<  [kmmcd]
>       159 root         0 SW   [pdflush]
>       160 root         0 SW   [pdflush]
>       161 root         0 SW<  [kswapd0]
>       209 root         0 SW<  [aio/0]
>       213 root         0 SW<  [nfsiod]
>       220 root         0 SW<  [cifsoplockd]
>       807 root         0 SW<  [kapmd]
>       873 root         0 SW<  [mtdblockd]
>       919 root         0 SW<  [rpciod/0]
>       925 root         0 SWN  [jffs2_gcd_mtd3]
>       927 root         0 SW<  [mmcqd]
>      1806 root      2908 R    -bash
>      2456 root      2072 R    ps
> ```

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p0 /mnt/disk
umount /sys
umount /tmp
cat /proc/mounts
```

> ```
>  rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
>  /dev/root / jffs2 rw 0 0
>  /proc /proc proc rw 0 0
>  /dev/mmcblk0p0 /mnt/disk ext2 rw,errors=continue 0 0
> ```

I guess I have to find a way to unmount `/dev/root` and `/` or `rootfs` but won't `/mnt/disk` be a problem because it will still be in use but, it is the SD card I want to chroot to?

```
umount /proc

cd /mnt/disk
pivot_root . old-root
mount -t proc none /proc
ls -l /proc/1
```

> ```
> -r--------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 auxv
> --w-------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 clear_refs
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:16 cmdline
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 coredump_filter
> lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 cwd -> //
> -r--------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 environ
> lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:16 exe -> /old_root  /sbin/init*
> dr-x------    2 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 fd/
> dr-x------    2 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 fdinfo/
> -r--------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 limits
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 maps
> -rw-------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 mem
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 mountinfo
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 mounts
> -r--------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 mountstats
> dr-xr-xr-x    5 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 net/
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 oom_adj
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 oom_score
> -r--------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 pagemap
> -r--------    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 personality
> lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 root -> //
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 sched
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 smaps
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:16 stat
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 statm
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 status
> dr-xr-xr-x    3 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 task/
> -r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 30 01:17 wchan
> ```

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

> ```
> rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
> /dev/root /old_root jffs2 rw 0 0
> /dev/mmcblk0p0 / ext2 rw,errors=continue 0 0
> none /proc proc rw 0 0
> ```

```
exec chroot . sh <dev/console >dev/console 2>&1
umount /old_root
```

> ```
> umount: can't umount /old_root/: Device or resource busy
> ```

```
fuser -m /old_root/
#> 1 # <= issue here
```

---

I would like to know if I forgot something (maybe my strategy is simply broken?)

I tried with `chroot / switch_root`.
I also tried to `mount --move /proc` and `/sys` instead of using the SD card rootfs.

Kernel version: 2.6.29.4 ← a rootfs exists so, is it possible to umount the root?
Busybox version: 1.16.1

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /proc/1/` after the `pivot_root`? (My guess is that it's not your `init` process doing the pivoting ...)

Comment: @frostschutz Indeed...
ls: /proc/1: No such file or directory

Comment: You do have to mount /proc for that obviously... anyway if your `init` won't free up the `/` then you won't be able to umount it. Other possibilities are loop/md/dm devices...

Comment: @frostschutz I tried to mount /proc but I am not so sure about the mount options (--move would make sense to me but I still cannot unmount after the pivot_root). Is there any other mount point I should mount (I tried with /proc and /sys)

Comment: `mount -t proc none /proc`. if there are other mounts in the old root (check `/proc/mounts`) you have to umount those first too ... there is not too much point in moving proc sys ... and it's just `--move old new`, no need for `-t`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my issue was easy to solve, I just needed to relaunch init running `init u`

Pitfalls:

- Concerning the unmount of the old partition, we don't care about the `rootfs` neither about the `/dev/root`
- once I chrooted, I didn't mount a `/proc` and consequently, `fuser -m /old_root` gave no output

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you are executing the command `umount /old_root` still from the old root, and therefore it is busy.

I once did a similar script, and the following worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

 mount -v -n -t proc  -onodev,noexec,nosuid proc  /proc
 mount -v -n -t sysfs -onodev,noexec,nosuid sysfs /sys

 mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/root                           

 mount --move /dev  /mnt/root/dev/                                  
 mount --move /proc /mnt/root/proc/                                 
 mount --move /sys  /mnt/root/sys/                                  

 echo "Switching root filesystem..."
 cd /mnt/root                                               
 pivot_root . mnt/tmp/                                          

 exec chroot . /sbin/init
```

then, inside the new root, the first command the new init executes is `umount /mnt/tmp/`.

Comment: Actually, I think my problem is related to the `/dev/root` entry in `/proc/mounts` I cannot manage to `umount` / `mount --move`.
(the rootfs is not umontable as far as I know but I'm not sure if it's an issue or not)