# umount /dev: Invalid argument

Tags: mount, chroot

I would like to chroot to another rootfs and unmount the former one so, after mounting a SD card containing a rootfs (on `/mnt/disk/`) and killing almost every process, I tried to run:

```
umount /tmp
mount --move /proc /mnt/disk/proc
mount --move /sys /mnt/disk/sys
```

and then, `mount --move /dev /mnt/disk/dev` which fails with the error message:

> mount: mounting /dev/ on /mnt/disk/dev failed: No such file or directory

---

Some more information:

- I also tried `umount /dev` giving

  > umount: can't umount /dev/: Invalid argument
  >   # (same error with /dev/root)
- The former rootfs is on a NAND partition (JFFS2)
- `/proc/cmdline` contains:

  > root=/dev/mtdblock3
- `mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock3 /mnt/disk/dev` works (mounts the former root)
  Could it be related to a filesystem conflict between the SD card and the root partition ?
- `cat /mnt/disk/proc/mounts`

  > rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
  >   /dev/root / jffs2 rw 0 0
  >   /proc /mnt/disk/proc proc rw 0 0
  >   /sys /mnt/disk/sys sysfs rw 0 0
  >   /dev/mmcblk0p0 /mnt/disk ext2 rw,errors=continue 0 0
- Kernel: 2.6.29.4
- busybox: 1.16.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# cat /mnt/disk/proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / jffs2 rw 0 0
/proc /mnt/disk/proc proc rw 0 0
/sys /mnt/disk/sys sysfs rw 0 0
/dev/mmcblk0p0 /mnt/disk ext2 rw,errors=continue 0 0

umount /dev: Invalid argument

mount: mounting /dev/ on /mnt/disk/dev failed: No such file or directory
```

There is no filesystem mounted at `/dev`, therefore you cannot unmount it or move it.  That is what these error messages mean.  (Possibly busybox `mount` uses more generic error messages than its heavyweight counterpart).

---

If the target `/dev/` isn't going to have the device nodes you need, hopefully you have a `MAKEDEV` in there you can use.

If you try copying them from the original `/dev/` using `cp -a`, there's a risk that the UIDs will not match the target rootfs, and hence permissions won't work as desired for non-root users.  (Less secure or "so secure it doesn't work").

Comment: ok, unmounting /dev doesn't make sense but why cannot I unmount `/dev/mtdblock3` ? (also triggers an invalid argument error but if I mount it at a random location I can successfully run `umount /dev/mtdblock3`). [`/dev/root` does not exist, that's why I'm focusing on `/dev/mtdblock3` shown by `proc/cmdline`.]

Comment: You can't unmount `/` because lol.  (You're using it.  Although from that error message, it sounds like it's special-cased as well).  chroot doesn't change that.  I'm pretty sure you can't unmount implicitly, and that's a terrible idea anyway.  Close resources explicitly in order to receive errors.  The solution you're looking for was created for old-style initrds (initial ramdisks).  Use `pivot_root`

Comment: Sorry I meant I cannot unmount my old root from the new.
(pivot_root <new_root> <old_root> and then umount /old_root/dev/mtdblock3)

Comment: that is not the command sequence documented in [pivot_root(8)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pivot_root.8.html).  Open a new question (or edit this one) to specify unambiguously what you have tried and what the result was.

Comment: Actually, I opened [another question about pivot_root()](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306406/unable-to-umount-after-pivot-root) earlier and then opened this one to solve it.
As you perfectly answered the question (how to umount /dev playing with chroot), I think we agree that this question is closed.

Comment: Right.  I'd be asking the same questions frostschutz has.